# how to merge two array in my self Pattern?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to combine 2 arrays in javascript into one.

```
var one=[11,22,33,44,55];
var two=[66,77,88,99,11];
```

i want combaine 2 above arraye in below Pattern:

```
three=[11,66,22,77,33,88,44,99,55,11];
```

how do merge 2 arrays in above Pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const result = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < Math.min(one.length, two.length); i++)
   result.push(one[i], two[i]);
```